# Schema.org/Organization - What's the real use of it?

Tags: google-schemas

Good day!

I cannot find a complete description of the very items that make this concreate schema useful for business in SERP. I realy don't understand why should irganization markup schema if it provide no benefits in search result? isn't it easier to create an account in Google My Business or in some Catalog with reviews on it? In this case we can see the snippet with 'rating stars'.

For example, there are two sniipets from search result:

- organization1 has Schema.org/Organization markup on its' page: 
  [Search result snippet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEkmy.png)
- organization2 has no markup on its' site, but has it's page in catalog Yelp: 
  [Search result snippet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuwCr.png)

Moreover, I cannot understand how can "aggregateRating" (based on a collection of reviews or ratings, of the item) calculate this rating?
Please, can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

Check the FAQ section with regard to Schema.org in the [About Section](http://schema.org/docs/faq.html) Answers related to your question are:

**Q: What is the purpose of schema.org?**

> Schema.org is a joint effort, in the spirit of sitemaps.org, to
>   improve the web by creating a structured data markup schema supported
>   by major search engines. On-page markup helps search engines
>   understand the information on web pages and provide richer search
>   results. A shared markup vocabulary makes easier for webmasters to
>   decide on a markup schema and get the maximum benefit for their
>   efforts. Search engines want to make it easier for people to find
>   relevant information on the web. Markup can also enable new tools and
>   applications that make use of the structure.

**Q: Why are Google, Bing, Yandex and Yahoo! collaborating? Aren't you competitors?**

> Currently, there are many standards and schemas for marking up
>   different types of information on web pages. As a result, it is
>   difficult for webmasters to decide on the most relevant and supported
>   markup standards to use.  Creating a schema supported by all the major
>   search engines makes it easier for webmasters to add markup, which
>   makes it easier for search engines to create rich search features for
>   users.

There's also a video on youtube about [using schema for SEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MV7a60xCV5c) for you business.

Comment: noogui, thanks for your answer. Still I've asked for concreat examples of benefits from using Schema.org/Organization. And you just copied the general info from 'Help'. :(

Answer (score 0):

Structured data is a standardized format of code that is added to a web page. It communicates specific information about a page to Google. This makes it easier for search engines to crawl and index your content faster. In other words, it provides the context search engines need to properly categorize your site and recommend it more accurately for relevant search queries.

Google is using this data to make their search engine more accurate by creating a knowledge graph. This graph is an interconnected map of entities that follows the relationship between different terms, facts, data, dates, and more. This allows Google to go from keyword matching to a context-rich search engine, capable of differentiating the Taj Mahal monument from the Taj Mahal casino in Atlantic City.

What it means for SEOs is that Google has given you a way to introduce your client’s brands and companies into their knowledge graph, making them real objects Google knows about and can recommend to users. Check out our [structured data guide](https://prerender.io/structured-data-for-seo/) on how to implement it on your site, including the recommended format for SEO and more on schema markups and aggregateRating.